# How to create a Request Http "GET" to url

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-services, api

I want to make a request http Webservice API to

`https://sms.vietguys.biz/api/u=[user]&pwd=[password]&from=[Title]&phone=[phonenumber]&sms=[ContentSMS]`

using javascript.

Can I do this on Sharepoint Online ?

When I handle by below code:

```
var urlstring =`https://sms.vietguys.biz/api/u=[user]&pwd=[password]&from=[Title]&phone=[phonenumber]&sms=[ContentSMS]`;
$.ajax({
    url: urlstring,
    success: function (data) { 
        //do smth with data
    },
    error: function(a,m){
       //process error
    }
```

I got this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load .No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'https://benhvienthuduc.sharepoint.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: that error suggests that you need to enable cors for your service, this [article](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) should help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://sms.vietguys.biz/api/u=[user]&pwd=[password]&from=[Title]&phone=[phonenumber]&sms=[ContentSMS]",
    success: function (data) { 
        //do smth with data
    },
    error: function(a,m){
       //process error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of security restriction that prevents requests being made from one domain to another ie from **xxx.sharepoint.com** is requesting **sms.vietguys.biz** . To overcome this a commonly used practice is [CORS](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) and another method is by using [JSONP](https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/)

Comment: Can you take me a example about CORS, plzz? sms.vietguys.biz is another organization, i can't using JSONP, because i can't code server side.

Comment: But if that api is not configured for cross domain calls then you cannot consume it from another domain

Answer (score 0):

As @Unnie inform that you have enable cross on server and if api server is not in your control then you cannot do it. for that you have to create proxy server who will take care CROS

There several options from that I will tell you two

1. If You can use azure then use azure function where you can make api proxy and do setting for CROS
2. Use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ In your case

   $.ajax({
       url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://sms.vietguys.biz/api/u=[user]&pwd=[password]&from=[Title]&phone=[phonenumber]&sms=[ContentSMS]",
       success: function (data) { 
           //do smth with data
           },
           error: function(a,m){
               //process error
           }
   });

But I will not use second option in production environment